# How to delete useless files after compiling with buildozer?

Tags: ubuntu, kivy

I'm developing android app with kivy using buildozer.
In my Ubuntu, after compiling buildozer, I think it creates log files or
create some sort of file that takes my hard disk.
Can you tell me where to find this kind of files and delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will create a directory at `~/.buildozer` and also a '.buildozer' in your project directory.

Note that if you delete these, their contents will be re-downloaded if you run buildozer again.

Comment: can you tell me how to delete it clean?

Comment: @KyungHoonBaek `rm -rf .buildozer ~/.buildozer` from your project directory